# Ajax Does Not Call An Appropriate Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ajaxq

I am trying to call another action rather than my default action from html razor form (in view), but it always calls default method. I used jquery ajax for it but unable to solve this problem. I have tried with following code.

**Html razor code :-**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InitialView", "AgreementRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "firstform", role = "form" }))
{

//Other Razor code

<input type="submit" value="Add Another" id="btnAddAnother" name="btnAddAnother" />

}
```

**Jquery Ajax Code :-**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$("#btnAddAnother").click(function(){
                e.preventDefault();
                var element = this;
                $.ajax({

                    url: "/AgreementRegistration/AddNew",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status == "Success") {
                            alert("Executed!!!");
                            $(element).closest("form").submit(); //Submit form
                        } else {
                            alert("Not Executed");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error occured!!!");
                    }

                });
            });

 });
```

In this, If I click on 'AddAnother' button, It calls default 'InitialView' action, I want to call 'AddNew' action instead. By using above jquery code, It doesn't execute. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: change the input type as button instead of submit

Comment: check for jquery error in the page

Answer (score 2):

You not passing the event (and therefore not canceling it). Change the code to

```
$("#btnAddAnother").click(function(e) { // add the parameter
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
```

or make it a button

```
<button type="button" id="btnAddAnother" name="btnAddAnother" />Add Another</button>
```

and delete `e.preventDefault;`

Comment: I tried with your suggestion, but It's not working for me.

Comment: What is not working? - this code will prevent the default submit (to `InitialView()` and instead go to `AddNew()`

Comment: And also remove the pointless `traditional: true` option and construct your url's correctly using `'@Url.Action("AddNew", "AgreementRegistration")',`

Comment: I checked it using debugger, but debugger niether enter into AddNew() method nor InitialView()

Comment: Then you have other errors with your code. Start by editing your question to show your controller methods.

Comment: And also check what errors your getting in the browser console.

Comment: In browser console it exit after 'data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData }),'  point.

Comment: What is `someData`? You need to show all the relevant code.

Comment: It works fine when I remove `data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData })`  from code

Comment: But that means you not passing any data to the method - what data are you wanting to send (and what is your controller method)?

Comment: If your problem has been solved, you should accept this or one of the other answers to close this out.

Answer (score 2):

You're hooking the event to the `click` event of the submit button, this means the form is still being submit using the standard POST method. Instead, you should hook to the `submit` event of the `form` element. Try this:

```
$("#firstform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.prop('action'),
        type: $form.prop('method'),
        data: { 'Options': someData },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Executed!!!");
            } else {
                alert("Not Executed");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code If You can use submit button so page is submit but you can use normal button so only onclick event function call so use folliwing code...

**CSHTML Page Code-**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("InitialView", "AgreementRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "firstform", role = "form" }))
{

//Other Razor code

<input type="button" value="Add Another" id="btnAddAnother" name="btnAddAnother" />

}
```

**SCRIPT CODE**

```
$("#btnAddAnother").click(function(){
                e.preventDefault();
                var element = this;
                $.ajax({

                    url: "/AgreementRegistration/AddNew",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status == "Success") {
                            alert("Executed!!!");
                            $(element).closest("form").submit(); //Submit form
                        } else {
                            alert("Not Executed");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error occured!!!");
                    }

                });
            });
```

Comment: with mapping event to the `$("#btnAddAnother").click(function(){` how thus `e.preventDefault();` works. map event `$("#btnAddAnother").click(function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

Change the type to `button` of the input

```
<input type="button" value="Add Another" id="btnAddAnother" name="btnAddAnother" />
```

You can do this by slightly changing your code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnAddAnother").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            .
            .
        });
        return false;
    });
 });
```

hope this helps

Comment: does `jquery.js` and `jquery-validate.js` are loaded. Check any error is showing in the page by inspecting the page in `chrome browser`